How to get rid of a mysterious phantom USB device
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on a 7-year-old HP laptop. Recently, my laptop has started to take abnormally long (ca. 30 seconds or more) to recognize newly connected devices.
In dmesg there constantly appears a string of messages like the following:
[  798.629081] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[  798.743196] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  799.167010] usb 1-8: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  799.275264] usb usb1-port8: attempt power cycle
[  799.655121] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[  799.655326] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[  799.859017] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[  800.066970] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 40, error -71
[  800.067082] usb 1-8: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[  800.446967] usb 1-8: new full-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[  800.447171] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[  800.651121] usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
[  800.858833] usb 1-8: device not accepting address 41, error -71
[  800.858870] usb 1-8: WARN: invalid context state for evaluate context command.
[  800.858917] usb usb1-port8: unable to enumerate USB device

There is no device corresponding to the port described above:
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c34b Logitech, Inc. USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04ca:706e Lite-On Technology Corp. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

I am also not aware of any USB devices missing from this list, and all of the physical ports on my laptop are still working.
There's no entry corresponding to this port under /sys/bus/usb:
# ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb
1-1  1-4  1-6  1-7  bind  uevent  unbind  usb1  usb2

This also doesn't correspond with any physical port I can find.
So my questions are:

Could this port be related to the abnormally long times it takes to recognize USB devices?
How do I tell the kernel just to ignore this port?

Thanks!

Try this go to /etc/modprobe.d/options if there is no options make a file and write in it options usbcore use_both_schemes=y see if it works for you, if it does, let me know and I will write an answer instead.

You need to reboot after doing this
